# BLE control from Widgets?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I know very well how to directly connect to BLE hardware, and send/recieve data using `CBCentralManager`from an iOS app.

I am trying to find a way to create a `BLE` connection and data exchange from `Today's view` (`Extension`?).

That means creating a widget with buttons , where each button send some BLE data, for example turn on/off a light.

I couldn't find any example online. Can I manipulate my Swift BLE code to do so?

Comment: would you please send me some important links or anything about to send and send and receive data using wireless DEX Bluetooth device.